# Unwanted space between flex items of different size in two column layout

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make items with different `height` values to nicely wrap in a `flex` container of fixed `width`.

A simplified code of the problem is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item bigger">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 300px;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 8px;
  background-color: green;
}

.bigger {
  height: 160px;
}
```

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/72v10k6w/).

The result:

[image]

The problem is i cannot get rid of the space between divs `2` and `4`.

I've tried playing with the `align-items`, `justify-content` and `align-content` properties on the parent container, but i cannot make it work.

This is the result i would like to achieve:

[image]

I'd really appreciate any suggestions on how to fix the layout (if possible).